# Compute This Standard Deviation More Efficiently

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

> The owner of an automobile insures it against damage by purchasing an insurance policy with a deductible of $250$. In the event that the automobile is damaged, repair costs can be modeled by a uniform random variable on the interval $(0, 1500)$.  Determine the standard deviation of the insurance payment in the event that the automobile is damaged.

Let $X$ denote the damage, so it is the uniform random variable on $(0, 1500)$.  Then, we set $Y$ as the payment:

$$Y \ \ = \ \ \begin{cases}
\ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{when } & X < 250 \\
\ X - 250 & 250 \le X \le 1500
\end{cases}$$

The computation for $\text{var } Y = E(Y^2) - (EY)^2$ is straight forward, but ugly:

\begin{align}
E(Y^2) \ \ & = \ \ \int_{250}^{1500} (x - 250)^2 \cdot \tfrac{1}{1500} \, dx \\
EY \ \ & = \ \ \int_{250}^{1500} (x - 250) \cdot \tfrac{1}{1500} \, dx
\end{align}

It will definitely take  me (and many others ...) several attempts and a lot of time to get to the correct answer.  This was supposed to be an exam question, and we need a better way to do this.  Any suggestion?

**Computation:**

Let me be more specific.  The integration is not difficult.  It is at the end when you have so many substitutions that I screw up:
\begin{align}
E(Y^2) \ \ & = \ \ \int_{250}^{ 1500} (x-250)^2 \cdot \tfrac{1}{1500} \, dx \\
& = \ \ \int_{250}^{ 1500} \tfrac{x^2 - 500x + 250^2}{1500} \, dx \\
& = \ \ \frac{1}{1500} \left[ \, \frac{x^3}{3} - 250x^2 + 250^2x \, \right]_{\, 250}^{\, 1500} \ \ = \ \ ???
\end{align}
The change of variable helps.  I think too often I just dive straight into the question and don't see that I'm doing things stupidly.  You're right; until I clean up my calculations, I will never get far.

Comment: Those integrals are very straightforward, no?  you might find it easier (in both cases) to change variables (letting $q=x-250$) but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: I think it may be best to show us how you would calculate the integrals so we can point you towards quicker ways. The reason is that to me these integrals are very straightforward and will usually take only one line to calculate, so you are on quite a fast track if you get comfortable with the integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the Bernoulli random variable $$L = \begin{cases} 1, & X \ge 250, \\ 0, & X < 250, \end{cases}$$ with $\Pr[L = 1] = \frac{1500-250}{1500} = \frac{5}{6}.$ Then we can write $Y = L(X - 250)$, and $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{Var}[Y] &= \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid L]] + \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid L]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[Y \mid L]^2 \Pr[L = 1] (1 - \Pr[L = 1]) + \operatorname{Var}[Y \mid L] \Pr[L = 1],
\end{align*}$$ by the law of total variance.  The conditional expectation is $$\operatorname{E}[Y \mid L] = \begin{cases} 625, & L = 1 \\ 0, & L = 0, \end{cases}$$ because the midpoint of $[250, 1500]$ is $\operatorname{E}[X \mid L = 1] = 825$, then subtract off $250$ to get $625$.  The conditional variance is clearly $$\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid L] = \begin{cases} \operatorname{Var}[X \mid L] = \frac{390625}{3}, & L = 1 \\ 0, & L = 0, \end{cases}$$ since the variance is not affected by a location shift, and the variance of a $\operatorname{Uniform}(a,b)$ random variable is $(b-a)^2/12$.  Then we have $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = 625^2 \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} + \frac{390625}{3}\cdot \frac{5}{6} = \frac{1953125}{12}.$$

Whether this approach is **easier** than the direct integration is another question entirely.

---

It is worth noting that this approach works in a more general context:  suppose we have a ground-up loss random variable $X$ and the insurer's amount paid on the claim $Y = (X - d)_+ = \max\{X-d, 0\}$ subject to an ordinary deductible of $d$.  Then we have $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \left((\operatorname{E}[X \mid X > d] - d)^2 \Pr[X \le d] + \operatorname{Var}[X \mid X > d]\right)\Pr[X > d].$$  So if we can compute the moments of the conditional loss random variable in excess of the deductible, we can get the desired variance from the above.  For example, if $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\mu)$, then the memorylessness property gives us $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid X > d] = d + \operatorname{E}[X] = \mu + d, \quad \operatorname{Var}[X \mid X > d] = \operatorname{Var}[X] = \mu^2,$$ and the formula simplifies to $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \mu^2 (2 - e^{-d/\mu}) e^{-d/\mu}.$$  Of course, this computation is simple because of memorylessness.

---

In regard to the original integration, which I still think is the simplest approach, we should note $$\int_{x=250}^{1500} \frac{(x-250)^k}{1500} \, dx = \int_{u=0}^{1250} \frac{u^k}{1500} \, du = \left[\frac{u^{k+1}}{1500(k+1)}\right]_{u=0}^{1250} = \frac{1250^{k+1}}{1500(k+1)},$$ for $k > 0$, using the simple substitution $u = x - 250$, $du = dx$.  Thus we simply have $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \frac{1250^3}{1500(3)} - \left(\frac{1250^2}{1500(2)}\right)^2.$$